# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() ...kindly help me out

Tags: python

```
model=SmallerVGGNet.build(width=IMAGE_DIMS[1],height=IMAGE_DIMS[0],depth=IMAGE_DIMS[2],classes=len(mlb.classes),finalAct="sigmoid")
```

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() ?
 kindly help me out in this

Comment: I think we will need a bit more context. What is `mlb.classes`? Where is it defined?

Comment: Whatever `mlb` is, its attribute `classes` seems to be `None`.

Comment: print("[INFO] class labels:")
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
labels = mlb.fit_transform(labels)

# loop over each of the possible class labels and show them
for (i, label) in enumerate(mlb.classes_):
    print("{}. {}".format(i + 1, label))

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `mlb.classes` is not assigned properly and it is `None`. It is hard to tell more without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: can it be the python version problem i am using 3.6.

Comment: Are you sure mlb.classes is assigned properly? Can you add the line which assigns mlb or mlb.classes the value?

Comment: print("[INFO] class labels:")
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
labels = mlb.fit_transform(labels)

# loop over each of the possible class labels and show them
for (i, label) in enumerate(mlb.classes_):
    print("{}. {}".format(i + 1, label))

Comment: I have checked the sklearn documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html.
You may have to use mlb.classes_ instead of mlb.classes.

Comment: ValueError: ('Input data in `NumpyArrayIterator` should have rank 4. You passed an array with shape', (0,))  sir now its showing